# Dynamically fill a form field based on iframe ID

Tags: iframe, dynamic

I've seen lots of articles about how to pass values from a form field to an iframe - but none the other way round - So can this be done?

I'm calling an external form from another domain (another site we own and have access to) in an iframe like this:

Domain one:

```
<!--display external form in iframe - 
change the ID name to populate one form field -->
<iframe id="blue" name="blue" scr="domain-two-page.html" width="200px" >
```

The form located on domain two has a hidden field that I need to populate, based on the ID or name of the iframe element ID "blue".

This needs to be able to be changed to green, black or whatever, and the ID needs to pass to the form field from the iframe.

Maybe something like this in the form that's contained on domain two?

```
<script> 
$id = getElementById('ID').value ="variable"; 
</script>
```

And the form field:

```
 <!-- the form field value changes with the iframe ID -->
 <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield1" value="$id" />
```

But I am not sure!  Can anyone help please?

NB: Domain one is HTML and domain two is PHP!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is not possible due to XFS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can't do what you want easily to avoid XSS attacks, but i think (but i did not test it) that  you cand do something in this case to pass data to the iframe through his src:

```
<iframe id="blue" name="blue" scr="http://otherdomain.com/domain-two-page.html#blue" width="200px" >
```

in the other domain you could do:

```
window.onLoad = function(){
    color = window.data.hash;
}
```

And so you can use color in the second document as you wish

In the first domain (where the iframe is) you can have a function that "sends" data like this:

```
function dataSend(data){
    iframe.src = "http://otherdomain.com/domain-two-page.html#"+data
}
```

Basically you have a variable in the second domain which depands from the hash, and you can change the hash dinamically in the first domain.

EDIT - you have two possibilities i think:

you have two possibilities i think:

1) `<iframe width="300px" height="450px" allowtransparency="yes"  src="domaintwo/search.php#EK"  name="EK"  id="EK"  > </iframe>`

2) on domain 2

```
 window.onLoad = function(){ color = window.data.hash; } 
//now copy that value in the value of the hidden field
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[name="PrefferedAirlines"]').val(color);
});
```

or

1) `<iframe width="300px" height="450px" allowtransparency="yes"  src="domaintwo/search.php?formvalue=EK"  name="EK"  id="EK"  > </iframe>`

2)on domain 2

```
<?php $color = $_GET['formvalue']; ?>
```

Comment: Hmmm - I think I understand - but how to use the hash data to fill the form field ?  Basically, the iframe holds a search form that has one hidden field that should be changeable - The iframe ID should be changeable by the client according to what form they want to display to their user.  So - how to pass a change variable from within the iframe's code and use that identifier to fill-in one specific form field?

Comment: This is what I have so far:   <iframe id="blue" name="blue" scr="http://otherdomain.com/domain-two-page.html#blue" width="200px" > and on domain two:  
 
  window.onLoad = function(){
    color = window.data.hash;
}                                                                                                           and in the form field..... <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield1" <?php echo $color;? />  - but that's not working ! I need to pass the color into php in the form field yes? - how to do that ?

Comment: This worked perfectly:  thanks1) <iframe width="300px" height="450px" allowtransparency="yes"  src="domaintwo/search.php?formvalue=blue"  name="blue"  id="blue"  > </iframe>

2)on domain 2

<?php $color = $_GET['formvalue']; ?>

Let me know if any of this works!

  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfieldblah" value="<?php  echo(htmlentities($_GET['formvalue'])); ?>" />